# Is this how cable networking works?

Tags: current, network, internet, satellite

I am studying about how cable networks transmit data to various TV channels on our TV screen. It is fascinating to see how they work.

After studying different articles online, I have made points as to how the process works. There is no single article which can just directly tell all about it. Everyone has given small points. Please help in correcting me.

A single TV channel broadcasts a series of TV programs made by many different people.

I am assuming the transmission media to be radio waves.

1. The required video is recorded and this data is sent to the required channel provider’s antenna. Like BBC , Star Gold , W&B.
2. Channel provider will then send this data to the company who makes TVs - like LG , Samsung. They are the cable company.
3. They then transmit data to various geographical locations on the globe.  They can’t do it by directly sendoing radio to antenna of TVs since:

   - The radio waves can be interrupted by mountains, etc.
   - Radio waves can only be transmitted along a straight line.
4. The cable company sends the radio waves of the recordings to a satellite. The satellite then is easily able to send the radio waves in a straight line to different antenna of TV.
5. The antenna then receives the data and transmits it to the TV through a coaxial cable which is connected from the antenna to TV.

Henceforth at the end we receive the required TV channel.

Comment: You might want to start with a basic book about old fashioned over the air (OTA) TV transmission.  This came first.  Then when the internet came about, stations/broadcasters started sending their content over the internet.  Then in the mid 90's or early 20's, a switch was made over to digital TV OTA transmission.

Comment: @SteveSh K , I will also check that. Should I guess that I am either missing or wrong at the way it works.

Comment: There are a few misconceptions here. For example, TV manufacturers are not cable companies and are not involded in propagating broadcast tv. Normal TV antennas (not satellite dishes) receive terrestrial signals that are broadcast from nearby towers and do not involve sattelites. Cable TV (as in your question title) differs in that the last part of the journey is over a cable network instead of through the air.

Comment: TV manufacturers have nothing to do with broadcasting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because off topic

Comment: @DavideAndrea It will be beneficial if you also explain why so that I , as a user will know how to correct myself the next time & not vote to close it without any information given.

Comment: S.M.T - As I hinted at in my answer, this question is very broad, and someone could write a whole book on this topic.  You should try and ask specific, narrow questions that can be answered in less than a half dozen or so of paragraphs.

Comment: @SteveSh K. Thank you , I will work on that.

Comment: There are many ways to broadcast television: satellite, terrestrial radio (transmitters on the ground) and cable.  Some systems use a mixture of those.  Plus analog and digital television work differently.  And there are several different ways to send data over cables.

Answer (score 3):

This is much too broad a topic to cover in a Q&A forum such as this.  But let's start with a couple of your statements first.  I'm going to focus on traditional over the air (OTA) TV broadcasts, in order to keep things simple and not muddy the water with cable and satellite providers.

Note that from a timeline perspective, things went something like this:

B&W TV -> Color TV -> Satellite -> Streaming -> Digital

*"The required video is recorded & this data is sent to the required channel provider’s antenna. Like BBC , Star Gold , W&B."*

In the early days of TV, up through the 1950's say, most TV shows were live broadcast.  They were not recorded.

*"Channel provider will then send this data to the company who makes TV’S Like LG , Samsung. They are the cable company."*

Content/program provider would probably be a better term here.  But they don't send their content to the TV makers.  They send, or their content is bought by,  major TV networks like ABC, NBC, BBC.  Those networks then transmit/send that content to local TV stations.  Those TV stations then broadcast (send) that content over the airwaves using channels (RF frequencies) assigned by their local authority, the FCC here in the US.  Those signals can then be picked up by a TV set within range of the station, usually 50-100 miles of the station, maybe longer depending on the frequency the TV station is using, its power output, and terrain.

The range of OTA TV reception is limited, and so that same content is broadcast by stations in different area/towns/cities.  Most places in the US are within range of a couple of local stations and so can receive those broadcasts on their TV sets (Samsung, LG, etc).

Comment: Thank you so much for writing in details.

Answer (score 0):

Thought experiment:

- You have DVDs, video tapes or program material stored on your computer.
- You can create your own (illegal) TV station by (somehow) feeding the video and audio signals to a TV transmitter beside your player and connect that to an antenna on your roof. That's what broadcasting companies do. The transmitter sends the broadcast on one of channels allocated to it.
- If you like you could transmit the programs by cable (with suitable amplifiers) to your neighbours. That's what the cable companies do.

No need to involve TV manufacturers. The receiver just tunes into the required channel to pick up that program without interference from neighbouring channels.

Comment: K. So , there is like no password or someone controlling who has the authority to accept it first & then transmit the signals further.